# Rename all old branch script

Tags: git, branch, rename

How can I rename all branch where the last commit older than 31/12/2019 adding "OLD_" before the actual name on the remote repository

Comment: You can write a script (Python, Shell). Firstly git branch --all, then go to each branch inside the loop, the gil log and check last commit time and then you can rename .

Comment: a bash 1-liner would be able to do this, as @DeepeshUniyal suggests

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that does something like you want (+ example).

Here's a list of some random branches of mine that were last updated in 2018 which we'll run the script on. This script requires you to have a local copy of each branch, but i'll show at the end how to modify the script to be fully automated (i'm not much for automating things that end up on the remote).

```
    zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/jspaint (master)
    $ git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate' --format='%(refname)%09%(committerdate)' 
    refs/heads | sed -e 's-refs/heads/--'

    master          Mon Aug 31 13:54:23 2020 +0200
    newnewbr        Tue Aug 28 00:08:31 2018 +0200
    newbranch       Tue Aug 28 00:06:51 2018 +0200
    gh-pages        Tue Feb 6 21:12:34 2018 +0100
    some_branch     Thu Feb 1 20:57:43 2018 +0100
    test            Thu Feb 6 18:47:16 2014 -0800
```

Script:

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    for k in $(git branch | sed /\*/d); do
      if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='2019-12-31' -s $k)" ]; then
        git branch -m $k OLD_$k
      fi
    done
```

Output of running the script:

```
zrrbite@ZRRBITE MINGW64 /d/dev/git/jspaint (OLD_test)
$ git branch
  OLD_gh-pages
  OLD_newbranch
  OLD_newnewbr
  OLD_some_branch
* OLD_test
```

Now you could push those branches and delete the old ones on the remote, manually. If you wanted to push the renamed branch and delete the old ones automatically you could re-write the script to:

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    for k in $(git branch | sed /\*/d); do
      if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='2019-12-31' -s $k)" ]; then
        git branch -m $k OLD_$k
        git push origin --delete $k
        git push origin OLD_$k
      fi
    done
```

If you want to take it even further and assume that you have no local branches checked out you could instead:

- check `git branch -r` (for remote branches)
- check out the branch and rename it if applicable
- push the branch
- delete the old

If you have a lot of branches, and don't have a local copy, then it is probably wise to try this approach.

Comment: **I think there is an error on this line 

if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='2019-12-31' -s $k)" ]; then

The script rename branch which had commits aftre 31/12/2019 too, and this is not correct**

Comment: You're right. I realize the script is renaming any branch that has _any_ commit earlier than 2019-21-31. I'll get it fixed up.

Comment: or instead of pulling out the branches that have the last commit before 2019-12-31, branches created before 2019-12-31 are fine too